# How to search multidimensional array with array of keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Imagine that you have the following data structures. The config one is a hash of config values. The search is an array of hash keys to pull a config value from the config hash.

```
$config['users']['students']['default']['school'] = 'Garfield High';
$config['users']['students']['default']['domain'] = 'ghs.com';
$config['users']['teacher']['default']['fruit'] = 'apple';
$config['school']['superintendent'] = 'Boris York';

$search[] = 'users';
$search[] = 'students';
$search[] = 'default';
$search[] = 'school';
```

What's the most efficient way to use the $search array to get the value "Garfield High."

This sounds like a school assignment, but really it isn't. I've wandered down a rabbit hole, and while I'll probably abandon this thing that I'm doing, I'm curious how best to solve this problem. It seems like it should be easy, but for some reason, I'm stumped.

The method to extract values from $config should work with any $search array size. It needs to work with $search = array('school', 'superintendent') as well.

```
public function get($search, $config) {
    // Somehow pull value from $config

}
```

Comment: Do you ONLY want the end value returned. For example, search of 'teacher' returns 'apple' and search of 'school' returns 'Garfield High' and 'Boris York' as a two-item array?

Comment: Not really, because you could $config['users']['students']['highschool']['domain'] that could have the value 'highschool.ghs.com.' The end key would be 'domain' but the path to it would go through 'highschool' rather than 'default', for instance. Yes, I only want the end value, but the end value keys aren't unique in of themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a simple loop, using each element of `$search` as the key in the next level of the array being searched.

```
public function get($search, $config) {
    $result = $config;
    foreach ($search as $key) {
        if (is_array($result) && isset($result[$key])) {
            $result = $result[$key];
        } else {
            return false; // not found
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/nNcImp)

Comment: @Halfstop I've added a demo showing that my code works.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution with `RecursiveIteratorIterator` class:

```
$config = ['users' => ['students' => ['default' => ['school' => 'Garfield High'], 'highschool' => ['domain' => 'highschool.ghs.com']]]];

$search1 = ['users', 'students', 'default', 'school'];
$search2 = ['users', 'students', 'highschool', 'domain'];

function getConfigItem($search = [], $config = []) {
    $iterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveArrayIterator($config), \RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
    $result = "";
    foreach ($iterator as $k => $v) {
        if ($search[$iterator->getDepth()] == $k && is_string($v)) {
            $result = $v;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

var_dump(getConfigItem($search1, $config));  // string 'Garfield High'

var_dump(getConfigItem($search2, $config));  // string 'highschool.ghs.com'
```

http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php